# Vuetify v-img does not provide an id to events

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am trying to get the `id` of various `v-img` components to enable further processing, but the defined `id` isn't found in the event handler. For other components, e.g. `v-chip`, the id is available as expected.
I have a working demo on the [vuetify playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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); the code is as follows:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-text-field v-model="msg" />
      <v-img
        :width="150"
        :id = "1"
        src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/parallax/material.jpg"
         @mousedown="mouseDown"
      ></v-img>
      <v-chip size="x-large" class="font-weight-bold" 
         :id = "2"
         @mousedown="mouseDown"
         > myChip
       </v-chip>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('Hello World!')
function mouseDown(e) {
  msg.value='component id is: ' +e.target.id;
}
</script>
```

I have tried wrapping the `v-img` in a `v-component` but that creates problems with sizing and arrangement. I also tried wrapping in a `div` but that didn't help.  .

The sample here is simplified as much as possible to show the difference between `v-img` and `v-chip`. In the real world, the id's will not be simple numbers (they will be used in a `v-for` loop). But more importantly the event handlers will be in an external drag-n-drop library which I am trying to develop. The library won't know what the elements are - maybe vueutify components, maybe just simple html buttons or list items. A snippet from the library:

```
 document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onMouseDown);
 .....
 .....
 onMouseDown(e) {
     if (e.target.id != this.el.id) 
        return;
     ......
```

but `e.target.id` is always empty for a `v-img`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event targets the `<img>` element, but the id is put on the parent container. So you can get it from there:

```
function mouseDown(e) {
  msg.value='component id is: ' + e.target.parentElement.id;
}
```

Here it is in the [updated Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

---

Alternatively you could pass it directly to the callback, which looks a bit stupid with a fixed id, but might make sense if you create the `v-img` in a loop:

```html
<v-img
  v-for="(src, index) in images"
  :id = "index"
  src="src"
  @mousedown="mouseDown($event, index)"
></v-img>
```

---

If you say it it necessary to work with event targets directly and you need the attribute on the `img` element, you can use a custom directive:

```
const vSetImgDropperId = (el, binding) => {
  const img = el.querySelector('img')
  img && (img.dataset.dropperId = binding.value)
}
```

In composition API, you can put this on the `v-img` tag (check the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/custom-directives.html) on how to register directives otherwise):

```html
<v-img
  ...
  v-set-img-dropper-id="'le-image-id'"
></v-img>
```

Have a look at the [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: Decent answer and explanation, thanks. 1+

Comment: @Moritz, thank you, that is helpful. I have added more info to the question to show what I am trying to do.

Comment: Don't really understand your comment! But anyway, maybe if the id is empty I can just try to get the id of the parent instead. Seems a bit hit-and-miss, though.

Comment: You could use a directive, have a look at the updated answer

Comment: @MoritzRingler, you may be able to help with this related (?) question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76189377/vuetify-how-to-bounce-an-image