# Vuetify: how to bounce an image

Tags: vuetify.js, css-animations

I have a project which uses `v-chip` components and when I move them around and drop them elsewhere, I have used a 'bounce' transition to animate them:

```
<Transition name="bounce">
        <v-chip  ......
```

and the css:

```
.bounce-enter-active {
  animation: bounce-in 0.5s;
}
@keyframes bounce-in {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.25);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

This works well, but if I try the same technique with a `v-img` there is no bounce. So, how do I bounce an image?

### Later edit

@Moritz 's answer below was very helpful, improved my 'bounce' and is a great answer to the question I originally posed.
However, it was @yoduh 's comment that led me to the key problem. I had changed the way the images were being moved, so in effect the reactive `v-img` didn't get a look-in to the DOM change. So I now have simply:

```
<v-chip  class="bounce-enter-active" ......
```

instead of:

```
<Transition name="bounce">
        <v-chip  ......
```

Maybe I should have added this as an answer, but it doesn't actually answer my original question!

Comment: I would guess it depends on the implementation of the drag and drop.  `<Transition>` according to the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html) applies animations when an element or component is entering or leaving the DOM.  If the drag and drop is not reinserting v-img into the DOM then no animation would activate.

Comment: In my working example with `v-chip`s, the chips are being dragged between rows and columns of a `v-container` - the same structure as I have with the `v-img` project.

Comment: @yoduh, thanks, you led me to the actual problem - see edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you don't see the animation because it happens while the image still loads. Have a look at the snippet to see the difference:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()

const app = {
  setup() {
    const isOn = ref(false)
    const loadUncached = ref(false)
    const showPreloaded = ref(false)
    const nonEmpty = ref(false)
    const rawSrc = 'https://www.neonpoodle.co.uk/cdn/shop/products/HeadInCloudsPink_620x.jpg?v=1554576513'
    const src = ref(rawSrc)

    const loadSrc = () => {
      const src = rawSrc + (loadUncached.value ? '?asfd=' + Math.random() : '')
      return !showPreloaded.value ? src : new Promise(resolve => {
        const img = new Image()
        img.onload = () => resolve(src)
        img.src = src
      })
    }
    setInterval(async() => {
      const doShow = !isOn.value
      if (doShow) {
        src.value = await loadSrc()
      }
      isOn.value = doShow

    }, 2000)

    return {
      isOn,
      loadUncached,
      showPreloaded,
      nonEmpty,
      src
    }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```css
.bounce-enter-active {
  animation: bounce-in 0.5s;
}

@keyframes bounce-in {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.25);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.non-empty{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main class="ma-4">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <v-switch v-model="loadUncached" label="load uncached (leads to stunted transition)"></v-switch>
        <v-switch v-model="showPreloaded" label="preload image (restores transition)" :disabled="!loadUncached"></v-switch>
        <v-switch v-model="nonEmpty" label="set background"></v-switch>
      </div>
      <Transition name="bounce">
        <v-img v-if="isOn" :src="src" width="100" :class="{'non-empty' : nonEmpty}"></v-img>
      </Transition>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to see the full animation, make sure that the image is loaded into cache before you show it. A simple way to do it is to put the url into an `Image` and wait for the `onloaded` event, at which point the image is loaded into cache:

```js
  const preloadSrc = (src) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const img = new Image()
      img.onload = () => resolve(true)
      img.src = src
    })
  }
  showVImg.value = await preloadSrc('/the/image/url')
```

---

There is also a [`@load`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-img/#events-load) event on `v-img`, but it is quite annoying to get it to work with a combination of `<Transition>` and `v-if`. But since you are using a real CSS animation, you could use it without `<Transition>` (if it is acceptable to leave the class after the animation finished):

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()

const app = {
  setup() {
    const rawSrc = 'https://www.quilkin.co.uk/shared/topright.png'
    const src = ref(null)
    const loaded = ref(false)

    setInterval(async() => {
      src.value = src.value ? null : rawSrc + '?asfd=' + Math.random()
      loaded.value = false
    }, 2000)

    return {src, loaded}
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```css
.bounce {
  animation: bounce-in 1s;
}

@keyframes bounce-in {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.25);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main class="ma-4">

      <v-img
        v-if="src"
        :src="src"
        width="100"
        :class="{'bounce' : loaded}"
        @load="loaded = true"
      ></v-img>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

---

Alternatively, you could also set a background color and fixed height and width on the `v-img`, then you see that background animated while the image loads.

---

Finally, to make sure the animation uses the image and not a scaled-down version, set [`image-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) to `crisp-edges` in your CSS. It seems to be enough to set it on the 0% keyframe of the animation:

```css
@keyframes bounce-in {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful suggestion and it will certainly help _improve_ the 'bounce' when I get it working. But in my case there's no bounce at all. I have made a jsfiddle based on your code, to show that if the animation is slowed down, it still shows even without your improvements: https://jsfiddle.net/6p05rjs2/ ..... after more tests, I think it's something else wrong in the new project, as I temporarily  changed the `v-img` to `v-chip` and still no bounce :(

Comment: Ah, in your fiddle, there actually is a bounce, but the image is blurred, so it is unrecognizable. This can be fixed with an `image-rendering` rule. I have added it to the snippets and a short description. With the rule I now get a full bounce.

Comment: thank you again for the extra help. I have now found the underlying problem (see edit), and will use your suggestions to acheive the best 'bounce' possible.

Comment: Also, thank you for showing how to show a `vuetify` project in a single-page demo. That will come in very handy for future questions.....

Comment: That's great! May it bounce happily. For single-page demos, https://play.vuetifyjs.com is also very helpful